# Pandas: dataframe.drop() lead to Memory Error

Tags: python, pandas

Using jupyter notebook 4.3, Python 3.5.2 x64.

code:

```
input_df2.drop('date',axis=1,inplace=True)
```

and then Memory Error:

```
MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-52-7b522953d49a> in <module>()
----> 1 input_df2.drop('date',axis=1,inplace=True)

c:\users\jiahao\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in drop(self, labels, axis, level, inplace, errors)
   1906             else:
   1907                 new_axis = axis.drop(labels, errors=errors)
-> 1908             dropped = self.reindex(**{axis_name: new_axis})
   1909             try:
   1910                 dropped.axes[axis_].set_names(axis.names, inplace=True)

c:\users\jiahao\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in reindex(self, index, columns, **kwargs)
   2819     def reindex(self, index=None, columns=None, **kwargs):
   2820         return super(DataFrame, self).reindex(index=index, columns=columns,
-> 2821                                               **kwargs)
   2822 
   2823     @Appender(_shared_docs['reindex_axis'] % _shared_doc_kwargs)

c:\users\jiahao\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in reindex(self, *args, **kwargs)
   2238                             'argument "{0}"'.format(list(kwargs.keys())[0]))
   2239 
-> 2240         self._consolidate_inplace()
   2241 
   2242         # if all axes that are requested to reindex are equal, then only copy

c:\users\jiahao\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in _consolidate_inplace(self)
   2799             self._data = self._data.consolidate()
   2800 
-> 2801         self._protect_consolidate(f)
   2802 
   2803     def consolidate(self, inplace=False):

c:\users\jiahao\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in _protect_consolidate(self, f)
   2788         """
   2789         blocks_before = len(self._data.blocks)
-> 2790         result = f()
   2791         if len(self._data.blocks) != blocks_before:
   2792             self._clear_item_cache()

c:\users\jiahao\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in f()
   2797 
   2798         def f():
-> 2799             self._data = self._data.consolidate()
   2800 
   2801         self._protect_consolidate(f)

c:\users\jiahao\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py in consolidate(self)
   3522         bm = self.__class__(self.blocks, self.axes)
   3523         bm._is_consolidated = False
-> 3524         bm._consolidate_inplace()
   3525         return bm
   3526 

c:\users\jiahao\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py in _consolidate_inplace(self)
   3527     def _consolidate_inplace(self):
   3528         if not self.is_consolidated():
-> 3529             self.blocks = tuple(_consolidate(self.blocks))
   3530             self._is_consolidated = True
   3531             self._known_consolidated = True

c:\users\jiahao\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py in _consolidate(blocks)
   4519     for (_can_consolidate, dtype), group_blocks in grouper:
   4520         merged_blocks = _merge_blocks(list(group_blocks), dtype=dtype,
-> 4521                                       _can_consolidate=_can_consolidate)
   4522         new_blocks = _extend_blocks(merged_blocks, new_blocks)
   4523     return new_blocks

c:\users\jiahao\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py in _merge_blocks(blocks, dtype, _can_consolidate)
   4539         # combination of those slices is a slice, too.
   4540         new_mgr_locs = np.concatenate([b.mgr_locs.as_array for b in blocks])
-> 4541         new_values = _vstack([b.values for b in blocks], dtype)
   4542 
   4543         argsort = np.argsort(new_mgr_locs)

c:\users\jiahao\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py in _vstack(to_stack, dtype)
   4585 
   4586     else:
-> 4587         return np.vstack(to_stack)
   4588 
   4589 

c:\users\jiahao\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\shape_base.py in vstack(tup)
    232 
    233     """
--> 234     return _nx.concatenate([atleast_2d(_m) for _m in tup], 0)
    235 
    236 def hstack(tup):

MemoryError:
```

However, if I restart jupyter notebook and run the same line, it will be okay.

Any idea to solve this problem?

Comment: your session accumulated a bunch of variables that took up memory.  When you restarted Jupyter, you dumped the memory for everything.  Rerunning that line was a non-issue at that point.